# unable to provision postgres12 database cluster using the AWS CDK

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

given the following code:

```js
// please note I created a wrapper around the cdk components, hence cdk.ec2 etc.

const vpc = new cdk.ec2.Vpc(this, `${appName}VPC`);
    const dbCredentials = cdk.rds.Credentials.fromGeneratedSecret('postgres');

    const engine = cdk.rds.DatabaseClusterEngine.auroraPostgres({ version: cdk.rds.PostgresEngineVersion.VER_12_6 });
    const parameterGroup = cdk.rds.ParameterGroup.fromParameterGroupName(this, 'ParameterGroup', 'default.aurora-postgresql12');

    // Create the Serverless Aurora DB cluster; set the engine to Postgres
    const dbcluster = new cdk.rds.DatabaseCluster(this, `${appName}Cluster`, {
      engine,
      parameterGroup,
      defaultDatabaseName: `${appName}DB`,
      credentials: dbCredentials,
      instanceProps: {
        instanceType: cdk.ec2.InstanceType.of(cdk.ec2.InstanceClass.R5, cdk.ec2.InstanceSize.LARGE),
        vpc,
        vpcSubnets: {
          subnetType: cdk.ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC
        },
        publiclyAccessible: true,
        scaling: { autoPause: cdk.core.Duration.seconds(600) } // Optional. If not set, then instance will pause after 5 minutes
      }
    });
```

Provided we use postgres11 - this code works without issue, when I try and install 12, I get the following error reported by the CDK:

The Parameter Group default.aurora-postgresql12 with DBParameterGroupFamily aurora-postgresql12 cannot be used for this instance. Please use a Paramet
er Group with DBParameterGroupFamily aurora-postgresql11 (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterCombination; Request ID: e
e90210d-070d-4593-9564-813b6fd4e331; Proxy: null)

I have tried loads of combinations for instanceType (most of which work in the RDS UI on the console) - but I cannot seem to install postgres12 - any ideas what I am doing wrong?

tried this as well:

```js
const vpc = new cdk.ec2.Vpc(this, `${appName}VPC`);
    const dbCredentials = cdk.rds.Credentials.fromGeneratedSecret('postgres');
//DEFINING VERSION 12.6 FOR ENGINE
    const engine = cdk.rds.DatabaseClusterEngine.auroraPostgres({ version: cdk.rds.PostgresEngineVersion.VER_12_6 });
//DEFINING 11 FOR PARAMETER GROUP
    const parameterGroup = cdk.rds.ParameterGroup.fromParameterGroupName(this, 'ParameterGroup', 'default.aurora-postgresql11');

    const dbcluster = new cdk.rds.DatabaseCluster(this, `${appName}Cluster`, {
      engine,
      parameterGroup,
      defaultDatabaseName: `${appName}DB`,
      credentials: dbCredentials,
      instanceProps: {
        instanceType: cdk.ec2.InstanceType.of(cdk.ec2.InstanceClass.R6G, cdk.ec2.InstanceSize.LARGE),
        vpc,
        vpcSubnets: {
          subnetType: cdk.ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC
        },
        publiclyAccessible: true,
        scaling: { autoPause: cdk.core.Duration.seconds(600) } // Optional. If not set, then instance will pause after 5 minutes
      }
    });
```

works like a dream - but installs engine v11.9 :( - I need >12 because I need to install pg_partman
somewhere along the line the engine is not. being properly set - or is hardcoded to 11

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```js
const AURORA_POSTGRES_ENGINE_VERSION = AuroraPostgresEngineVersion.VER_10_7
const RDS_MAJOR_VERSION = AURORA_POSTGRES_ENGINE_VERSION.auroraPostgresMajorVersion.split('.')[0]

const parameterGroup = ParameterGroup.fromParameterGroupName(
  scope,
  `DBPrameterGroup`,
  `default.aurora-postgresql${RDS_MAJOR_VERSION}`,
)

new ServerlessCluster(scope, `Aurora${id}`, {
  engine: DatabaseClusterEngine.auroraPostgres({
    version: AURORA_POSTGRES_ENGINE_VERSION,
  }),
  parameterGroup,
  defaultDatabaseName: DATABASE_NAME,
  credentials: {
    username: 'x',
  },
  vpc: this.vpc,
  vpcSubnets: this.subnetSelection,
  securityGroups: [securityGroup],
})
```